# Can I use Solr Sunspot gem for link-to autosuggest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, solr, sunspot

I would like my search bar to have a menu with suggestions that drops down as I begin typing, and when I click on one of the suggestions, it redirects me to the path of the suggestion, similar to what happens with Facebook. In other words, if I type in 'Ji', Jim would be among the drop-down suggestions, and clicking on Jim links me directly to his page. Does anyone know if I can do this with Sunspot? I found a gem that is supposed to be able to do this with Elasticsearch; might it also work with Sunspot?

I'm using Rails 4.0.10.

Comment: While you can do this with Sunspot, I found Elasticsearch to be easier to work with and to perform a bit faster. FYI, I am using both in production with similar configurations.

Comment: @kobaltz For some reason my computer won't download Elasticsearch. What did you use to accomplish that with Sunspot?

Comment: What OS are you running? I used callbacks to a controller with Typeahead.js

Comment: You mean for my computer? It's Ubuntu.

Comment: It's too much to type in a comment, but see this gist for installing elasticsearch. You can of course change the version to 1.3.4 to get the latest stable. https://gist.github.com/kobaltz/dce03f971cdaf37439a5